# Bad alignment with MusiXTeX

Tags: music

I used the following code to typeset a music sheet:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{music}
        \startextract
            \Notes \ibl0{'b}0 \qb0{_cbb} \tbl0\qb0a \enotes
        \endextract
    \end{music}
\end{document}
```

However, the result is misaligned and there is a gap after the first note.
[image: bad]

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a different notation.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
  \startextract
  \Notes \Qqbl {_j}iih \enotes
  \endextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

This yields

[image]

Anyway, removing a space in your input also fixes the issue

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
  \startextract
  \Notes \ibl0{'b}0 \qb0{_cbb}\tbl0\qb0a \enotes
  \endextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

Leave no space between notes.